# Return sum of values to the right of columns matching criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have each row of data organized in column pairs. In my example below, the column pairs would be `A:B, C:D, E:F, G:H` and the pattern would continue.

1. The first column in each pair contains `"PlayerStat:<statName>"` a string composed of `"PlayerStat:"` and a `statName` value which is itself a string such as `"MaxHealth` , `"Damage"` , `"PhysicalResistance"` , etc.
2. The second column in each pair contains `"exp;<n1>;<n2>;<n3>"` a string composed of `"exp;"` and three numbers `n` each delimited by semi-colons.

##### Example Row

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | PlayerStat:MaxHealth | exp;1;1;100 | PlayerStat:MaxHealth | exp;1;1;1000 | PlayerStat:MaxHealth | exp;1;2;10000 | PlayerStat:Damage | exp;1;1000;235 |

[image: Sample Row]

I want to SUM all the `n3` values where `statName="MaxHealth"`. So for this example, it'd be "100+1000+10000 = 11100" (highlighted in blue font in the screenshot above).

**Note:** Can't change the values and the blue font is just for the purposes of this example.

Some of the approaches I tried are shown below.

```
=INDEX(A1:H1, 0, MATCH("PlayerStat:MaxHealth", A1:H1, 0) + 1)
```

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(B4, ";"), 0, 4)
```

```
=FILTER(A1:H1, "PlayerStat:MaxHealth"=A1:H1)
```

[image: Approaches I tried]

[Link to my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1etStAxzjijtBRL2IgXUpjSrFJE0MCH1_LT-2nwXPuTo/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sum(iferror(filter()))` pattern, like this:

```
=sum( iferror( 
  filter( 
    iferror(regexextract(B1:H1, "\d+$") + 0), 
    A1:G1 = "PlayerStat:MaxHealth" 
  ) 
) )
```